# Elastic Search with group by and IN condition

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I can convert the following MySQL command into Elasticsearch query?

```
select chl_lvl2_code,chl_lvl2_nm from channel where chl_lvl1_code IN ('Retail','wholesale') group by chl_lvl2_code
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more, esp regarding what your ES schema is like? Is `channel` a type? Sounds like you could use multiple Term Queries inside a bool wrapper, e.g. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: yes we will need your document mappings to understand your document structure, since seems like you came from SQL background share sql data rows

Comment: yes channel is type.